# Drupal/Ubercart custom price php code for roles

Tags: php, drupal, roles, ubercart

Im building an e-commerce site for wholesale foods and the pricing for products change depending on the user logged in. Ive looked at member pricing and basically every module i could find to do with altering the price but they are either for drupal 6 or not really what im after. Im using Drupal 7 with ubercart 3.

Ive found this module http://drupal.org/project/uc_custom_price.  It adds a field within product creation that allows custom php code to be added to each individual product which is exactly what im after. however im not that good with php which is why ive been hunting modules instead of changing code.

What ive got at the moment is:

```
if ([roles] == 'test company') {
  $item->price = $item->price*0.8;
}
```

Except the [roles] part is the wrong thing to use there and it just throws errors.  Ive tried using things like $users->uid =='1' to try to hook onto a user like that but that didnt work either.

what would be the correct variable to put there?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [Drupal 7 global $user object](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user/7)

```
global $user; // access the global user object
if(in_array("administrator",$user->roles)){ // if its administrator
 $item->price = $item->price*0.8;
}elseif(in_array("vip",$user->roles)){ // if its a vip
 //..
}elseif(in_array("UserCompanyX",$user->roles)){ // if its a user from company X
 //..
}
```

or

```
if($user->roles[OFFSET] == "ROLE"){
 // price calculation
}
```

$user->roles is an array of the roles assigned to the user.

hope it helped

Comment: Thank you! exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own module with UC Price API: 
http://www.ubercart.org/docs/developer/11375/price_api

```
function example_uc_price_handler() {
  return array(
    'alter' => array(
      'title' => t('Reseller price handler'),
      'description' => t('Handles price markups by customer roles.'),
      'callback' => 'example_price_alterer',
    ),
  );
}

function example_price_alterer(&$price_info, $context, $options = array()){
  global $user;
  if (in_array("reseller", $user->roles)) { //Apply 30% reseller discount
    $price_info["price"] = $context["subject"]["node"]->sell_price - (
                           $context["subject"]["node"]->sell_price * 0.30) ;     
  }
  return;
}
```

See also: http://www.ubercart.org/forum/development/14381/price_alteration_hook